# How to split column by attribute

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to organize election data by the house, senate, & president races. They are all located in a column names 'Cand_Office' with letters representing what they ran for i.e.(h for the house, s for Senate, and p for president).

How can I split this one column('Cand_Office') into multiple columns representing each race?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html

Comment: example data please